# How to split a string in rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following query. I need to pull from a table, a reference for every order number (unique identifier). I will have in the end something like:

```
Order ID    Ref
A           Xz|Yz
```

But I want to have:

```
Order ID    Ref
A           Xz
A           Yz
```

The catch is for each order ID, I could have more or less references concatenated but they are always separated by `'|'`.

I need to use a Select statement somehow (to read the data in Tableau in the proposed format above).

Does anybody have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit the question description to show a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried to do. We need an example table structure, the data in that table, and the exact output you expect from that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version handles NULL list elements and multiple rows:

```
WITH tbl(order_id, ref) AS (
    SELECT 'A', 'Xz|Yz' FROM DUAL union all
    SELECT 'B', 'B1||B3' FROM DUAL union all
    SELECT 'C', '|C2|C3B3' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT order_id, regexp_substr(ref, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) ref
FROM tbl
CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(ref, '\|') + 1
  and prior order_id = order_id
  and prior sys_guid() is not null 
order by order_id;
```

[DB Fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=842b3ae271982f24f5702ce7d758383b)

Comment: Hey this is great. It covered all elements I needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use a recursive query with `CONNECT BY` and `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT order_id, TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(ref, '[^|]+', 1, level)) ref
FROM t
CONNECT BY instr(ref, '|', 1, level - 1) > 0
ORDER BY order_id, ref
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=009400f3dfa8722b70c4ef61a5324580)**:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 'A' order_id, 'Xz|Yz' ref FROM DUAL
)
SELECT order_id, trim(regexp_substr(ref, '[^|]+', 1, level)) ref
FROM t
CONNECT BY instr(ref, '|', 1, level - 1) > 0
order by order_id, ref
```

```
ORDER_ID | REF
:------- | :--
A        | Xz 
A        | Yz
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always have difficulty with that data, because its data is not normalised.

Specifically, the values in each column are currently [not atomic; they fail “first normal form”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_1NF).

The `|`-separated values should instead be broken out to separate values; for example, rows in some other table.

Comment: I know. Unfortunately it would be more time consuming to propose this method be changed from the source instead of finding a way to work around it.

Comment: @AndreiBudaes, do I understand correctly that the source of this data is *outside* the database; that is, you are importing serialised data from some external system? If so, it would be better to normalise the data on its way *into* the database.

Comment: I tried to get my head around what your links imply (data normalization). I think we are looking at two sides of the same coin. To satisfy the 1NF scenario I will break down the table as described above in a different table (within a WITH tbl AS (SELECT...) statement) before calling it later in my final table. I think adding the complexity of creating a separate KEY then order ID would not be relevant in my case though as the actual values in my references would most likely not repeat (Xy will not appear in other order IDs). I will probably use the connect by method to normalize.